# remain activity for badges

Tags: discussion

I want to know how many work I should do to earn specific badge. Examples are a lot for instance how many I edit remain for me to obtain related badge? questions are most at this type: How many work I should to obtain A badge. which work go to for example edit and A to its preferred badge.

Answer (score 2):

Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/badges and https://meta.askubuntu.com/help/badges.